# Is it right to use nested Async/Await or use it at the last function in the calling tree?

Tags: c#, .net

I am setting up a new server, and I want to expose Async API, this API will call a function and this function will call another function and so on, the last function in the calling tree will call an external service and use Async/Await code pattern. what is the right way to implement such API?

Shall I add Async/Await in all functions or just adding them in the last function?

E.g.

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(AnyTypeResponse))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAPI()
{
    var res = await MyFuncTree1();
    return Ok(res);
}

public async Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree1()
{
    var res = await MyFuncTree2();
    return res;
}

public async Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree2()
{
    var res = await MyFuncTree3();
    return res;
}

public async Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree3()
{
    var res = await CallExternalService();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: *How* are you going to call an async function without making the caller async too?

Comment: You need to make the whole call stack async/await, do not just add it to the last call. Also you do not need async/await for the methods other than MyAPI as you are not doing anything with the result, just return the task. Finally a good practice is naming your asynchronous methods that return a Task/Task<T> with the suffix Async.

Comment: @GSerg  public Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree2()
        {
            return MyFuncTree3();
        }

Comment: @Moath That is fine, as long as you never need to use the result of `MyFuncTree3` inside `MyFuncTree2`.

Comment: *this* code could actually be changed to only use await on the first call.  But only because you can refactor the awaited part to be the last line of the method.  Usually it's async all the way down.

Comment: Please see [eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Only the top function needs to be marked `async` in your example and `await` the result of `MyFuncTree1`. The others can just return the result task of the function they are calling (as the result is not used inside the function).

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AnyTypeResponse))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAPI()
{
    var res = await MyFuncTree1();
    return Ok(res);
}

public Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree1()
{
    return  MyFuncTree2();
}

public Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree2()
{
    return MyFuncTree3();
}

public Task<AnyTypeResponse> MyFuncTree3()
{
    return CallExternalService();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I want to ask you if I can mark the last function only Async/Await as this function is used in different areas in my project and it should be marked Async.

Comment: It needs to return a Task, but you only need to mark it as async if you do await inside it. All function all the way to the top needs to return task.